# How to change images on mouse over with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sample-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84bdg" style="display:block">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/poqn-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84xjz">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/kpth-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84yrh">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dtyh-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84gpl">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/gymr-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84dzo">
```

Is there anymethod to rotate thumbnails on mouse hover every second with javascript like many video tube sites?

I have a video gallery and I have multiple thumbs option but I dont know if its possible to change every second the images listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution :

```js
var i = 0;
var tid = null;
var sec = 1/3; // <- you want 1 here
var images = $("img").map(function () {
  return $(this).attr("src");
}).get();

$("img:gt(0)").remove();
$("img").hover(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  tid = setInterval(function () {
    i = (i + 1) % images.length;
    $this.attr("src", images[i]);
  }, 1000 * sec);
}, function () {
  clearInterval(tid);
  $(this).attr("src", images[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcMh.gif">
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQCT.gif">
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEgw.gif">
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCEw.gif">
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6QE.gif">
```

As an alternative, you could switch between a static GIF and an animated GIF :

```js
var gif = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IpaB.gif";
var agif = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYrPT.gif";

$("img").hover(function () {
  $(this).attr("src", agif);
}, function () {
  $(this).attr("src", gif);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IpaB.gif">
```

To make the GIF that you can see in the above code snippet, I have converted a [WEBP image from Youtube](https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/m3lF2qEA2cw/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=COyTh9YF&rs=AOn4CLAd9GA3NfrmqrF-X7uoAcifeS7YgQ) thanks to this online tool : https://ezgif.com/webp-to-gif.

Comment: Great I like it, thankyou very very much @leaf it worked also in my wordpress now :)

Comment: hey @leaf sorry for bothering you again but I would like to ask you if its possible to make this working for multiple items like in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jhudrp8v/1/ since Im working on my wordpress site with this when I posted the second post I saw that all images are replaced in one div only, please if you have time I know it must be very easy for you but Im here since this morning and still trying to make it working with different jquery selectors :(

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese Take a look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/jhudrp8v/11/ :-) The trick is to add a second parameter the jQuery function : `$("img", div)`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following...

```
<style type="text/css">
  .mvThumbs {
    position: relative;
  }
  .mvThumbs .mvThumb {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="mvThumbs">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84bdg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84xjz">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84yrh">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.mvThumbs img:gt(0)').hide();
  $(".mvThumbs").hover(function() {
    window.timer = setInterval(function() {
      $('.mvThumbs :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.mvThumbs');
    }, 1000);
  }, function() {
    clearInterval(window.timer);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Murat eyvallah, but there is a problem its increasing the number of images when I use inspect element in firefox I see thousend of images instead of 4 so its repeating your solution is nice and good but the problem is the page speed so many images will give a negative position in the page speed. Thankyou for your Answer Im still working with your code

Comment: I found another code on google since Im a newbea in js http://jsfiddle.net/ayNPS/387/ but this one is changing only the images in the same location and renaming the thumbs to 1.jpg 2.jpg etc and accepts only jpg

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese it's an example just. If you think about of page load speed, you can change src attribute with other images like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/47003sar/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `setInterval` that gets added on mouseenter and cleared on mouseleave, something like this:

```js
let hoverInterval;
let visibleIndex = 0;
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  hoverInterval = setInterval(() => {
    container.children[visibleIndex].style.display = 'none';
    visibleIndex++;
    container.children[visibleIndex].style.display = 'block';
  }, 1000);
});
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => clearInterval(hoverInterval));
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sample-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84bdg" style="display:block">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/poqn-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84xjz" style="display:none">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/kpth-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84yrh" style="display:none">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dtyh-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84gpl" style="display:none">
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/gymr-218x147.png" class="mvThumb" alt="" title="" id="thumb_i84dzo" style="display:none">
</div>
```